# Error: export 'ɵlooseIdentical' (imported as 'ɵlooseIdentical') was not found in '@angular/core while upgarding with 13 to 14.3.0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a project which uses Angular 13 and I want to update it to Angular 14.

When I try to update with:

ng update@angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14

I Get this error:--

./node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:2647:86-101 - Error: export 'ɵlooseIdentical' (imported as 'ɵlooseIdentical') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ContentChild, ContentChildren, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, DebugElement, DebugEventListener, DebugNode, DefaultIterableDiffer, Directive, ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER, ElementRef, EmbeddedViewRef, EnvironmentInjector, ErrorHandler, EventEmitter, Host, HostBinding, HostListener, INJECTOR, Inject, InjectFlags, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Input, IterableDiffers, KeyValueDiffers, LOCALE_ID, MissingTranslationStrategy, ModuleWithComponentFactories, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, NgModuleRef, NgProbeToken,
NgZone, Optional, Output, PACKAGE_ROOT_URL, PLATFORM_ID, PLATFORM_INITIALIZER, Pipe, PlatformRef, Query, QueryList, ReflectiveInjector, ReflectiveKey, Renderer2, RendererFactory2, RendererStyleFlags2, ResolvedReflectiveFactory, Sanitizer, SecurityContext, Self, SimpleChange, SkipSelf, TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, TemplateRef, Testability, TestabilityRegistry, Type, VERSION, Version, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation, ViewRef, asNativeElements, assertPlatform, createComponent, createEnvironmentInjector, createNgModule, createNgModuleRef, createPlatform, createPlatformFactory, defineInjectable, destroyPlatform, enableProdMode, forwardRef, getDebugNode, getModuleFactory, getNgModuleById, getPlatform, importProvidersFrom, inject, isDevMode, platformCore, reflectComponentType, resolveForwardRef, setTestabilityGetter, ɵALLOW_MULTIPLE_PLATFORMS, ɵAPP_ID_RANDOM_PROVIDER, ɵChangeDetectorStatus, ɵComponentFactory, ɵConsole, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵINJECTOR_SCOPE, ɵLContext, ɵLifecycleHooksFeature, ɵLocaleDataIndex, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵNG_ELEMENT_ID, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵNG_PROV_DEF, ɵNOT_FOUND_CHECK_ONLY_ELEMENT_INJECTOR, ɵNO_CHANGE, ɵNgModuleFactory, ɵNoopNgZone, ɵReflectionCapabilities, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵRender3ComponentRef, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ɵRuntimeError, ɵTESTABILITY, ɵTESTABILITY_GETTER, ɵViewRef, ɵ_sanitizeHtml, ɵ_sanitizeUrl, ɵallowSanitizationBypassAndThrow, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustHtml, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustResourceUrl, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustScript, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustStyle, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustUrl, ɵclearResolutionOfComponentResourcesQueue, ɵcoerceToBoolean, ɵcompileComponent, ɵcompileDirective, ɵcompileNgModule, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, ɵcompileNgModuleFactory, ɵcompilePipe, ɵcreateInjector, ɵdefaultIterableDiffers, ɵdefaultKeyValueDiffers, ɵdetectChanges, ɵdevModeEqual, ɵfindLocaleData, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible, ɵformatRuntimeError, ɵgetDebugNode, ɵgetDebugNodeR2, ɵgetDirectives, ɵgetHostElement, ɵgetInjectableDef, ɵgetLContext, ɵgetLocaleCurrencyCode, ɵgetLocalePluralCase, ɵgetSanitizationBypassType, ɵgetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵgetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵglobal, ɵinjectChangeDetectorRef, ɵinternalCreateApplication, ɵisBoundToModule, ɵisDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy, ɵisInjectable, ɵisListLikeIterable, ɵisObservable, ɵisPromise, ɵisStandalone, ɵisSubscribable, ɵivyEnabled, ɵmakeDecorator, ɵnoSideEffects, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵpublishDefaultGlobalUtils, ɵpublishGlobalUtil, ɵregisterLocaleData, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵresetJitOptions, ɵresolveComponentResources, ɵsetAllowDuplicateNgModuleIdsForTest, ɵsetClassMetadata, ɵsetCurrentInjector, ɵsetDocument, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵsetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵsetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵstore, ɵstringify, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵunregisterLocaleData, ɵunwrapSafeValue, ɵɵCopyDefinitionFeature, ɵɵFactoryTarget, ɵɵInheritDefinitionFeature, ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature, ɵɵProvidersFeature, ɵɵStandaloneFeature, ɵɵadvance, ɵɵattribute, ɵɵattributeInterpolate1, ɵɵattributeInterpolate2, ɵɵattributeInterpolate3, ɵɵattributeInterpolate4, ɵɵattributeInterpolate5, ɵɵattributeInterpolate6, ɵɵattributeInterpolate7, ɵɵattributeInterpolate8, ɵɵattributeInterpolateV, ɵɵclassMap, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate1, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate2, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate3, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate4, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate5, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate6, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate7, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate8, ɵɵclassMapInterpolateV, ɵɵclassProp, ɵɵcontentQuery, ɵɵdefineComponent, ɵɵdefineDirective, ɵɵdefineInjectable, ɵɵdefineInjector, ɵɵdefineNgModule, ɵɵdefinePipe, ɵɵdirectiveInject, ɵɵdisableBindings, ɵɵelement, ɵɵelementContainer, ɵɵelementContainerEnd, ɵɵelementContainerStart, ɵɵelementEnd, ɵɵelementStart, ɵɵenableBindings, ɵɵgetCurrentView, ɵɵgetInheritedFactory, ɵɵhostProperty, ɵɵi18n, ɵɵi18nApply, ɵɵi18nAttributes, ɵɵi18nEnd, ɵɵi18nExp, ɵɵi18nPostprocess, ɵɵi18nStart, ɵɵinject, ɵɵinjectAttribute, ɵɵinvalidFactory, ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep, ɵɵlistener, ɵɵloadQuery, ɵɵnamespaceHTML, ɵɵnamespaceMathML, ɵɵnamespaceSVG, ɵɵnextContext, ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata, ɵɵngDeclareComponent, ɵɵngDeclareDirective, ɵɵngDeclareFactory, ɵɵngDeclareInjectable, ɵɵngDeclareInjector, ɵɵngDeclareNgModule, ɵɵngDeclarePipe, ɵɵpipe, ɵɵpipeBind1, ɵɵpipeBind2, ɵɵpipeBind3, ɵɵpipeBind4, ɵɵpipeBindV, ɵɵprojection, ɵɵprojectionDef, ɵɵproperty, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate1, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate2, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate3, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate4, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate5, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate6, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate7, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate8, ɵɵpropertyInterpolateV, ɵɵpureFunction0, ɵɵpureFunction1, ɵɵpureFunction2, ɵɵpureFunction3, ɵɵpureFunction4, ɵɵpureFunction5, ɵɵpureFunction6, ɵɵpureFunction7, ɵɵpureFunction8, ɵɵpureFunctionV, ɵɵqueryRefresh, ɵɵreference, ɵɵregisterNgModuleType, ɵɵresetView, ɵɵresolveBody, ɵɵresolveDocument, ɵɵresolveWindow, ɵɵrestoreView, ɵɵsanitizeHtml, ɵɵsanitizeResourceUrl, ɵɵsanitizeScript, ɵɵsanitizeStyle, ɵɵsanitizeUrl, ɵɵsanitizeUrlOrResourceUrl, ɵɵsetComponentScope, ɵɵsetNgModuleScope, ɵɵstyleMap, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate1, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate2, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate3, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate4, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate5, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate6, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate7, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate8, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolateV, ɵɵstyleProp, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate1, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate2, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate3, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate4, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate5, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate6, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate7, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate8, ɵɵstylePropInterpolateV, ɵɵsyntheticHostListener, ɵɵsyntheticHostProperty, ɵɵtemplate, ɵɵtemplateRefExtractor, ɵɵtext, ɵɵtextInterpolate, ɵɵtextInterpolate1, ɵɵtextInterpolate2, ɵɵtextInterpolate3, ɵɵtextInterpolate4, ɵɵtextInterpolate5, ɵɵtextInterpolate6, ɵɵtextInterpolate7, ɵɵtextInterpolate8, ɵɵtextInterpolateV, ɵɵtrustConstantHtml, ɵɵtrustConstantResourceUrl, ɵɵvalidateIframeAttribute, ɵɵviewQuery)

[export 'ɵlooseIdentical'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpwF.png)

Can someone help me with this error how can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.